how to reset one particular exposed filter with a button click
I have an exposed filter for a list of states on a view.  I want the select field to automatically default back to "Any" after the person hits submit and gets his result view , and then clicks on any other button.  is there any way to do this? I have tried using various hooks, hook_form_alter, hook pre_view and cant seem to find a way to do this.

Unfortunately, it may not be possible. Views exposed filters have this weird situation where they execute the query on load, so if you reset the filter, it would probably load the default query.

If you just want the options to reset on the front end couldn't you just use a small bit of javascript?

It's not UX friendly in the first place. I would advice to go with a reset button instead.

I added a .js script with this code :
Drupal.behaviors.map_filters = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
  var clearBtn = document.getElementById('edit-field-geofield-proximity-collapsible--2');
  var stateSelect = document.getElementById('edit-field-address-administrative-area--2');
  clearBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      stateSelect.value = 'All'; 
  }, false);

}

};
